# Error message : MongoServerError: bad auth :Authentication failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

What is the reason behind this error?
this code I am using to connect to DB.

```
const uri =`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.xft2s.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
```

Comment: Did you set the correct DB name? (`myFirstDatabase`)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have access to your env contents first, by adding this line `console.log(process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD)`.